# PartialAsync instead of AJAX?

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC 6 project, I am exploring all options to dynamically display async content. For example, replacing AJAX calls with `@await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName")`. I am searching for such approach, because I've found out that parallel AJAX calls cannot properly use and persist TempData between the requests (even if I use `Keep();` or `Peek();` methods), which is crucial for my implementation.

Since, my AJAX calls consume endpoints, which on other hand extract and manipulate information from external APIs through HTTP calls (i.e. long running tasks), I am wondering if it is safe to use `@await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName")` as a replacement for my (3) AJAX calls, without introduction of dangerous deadlocks and bugs?

My idea is to display the View with loaders and after the data is fetched from the 3 calls, to display it on the view as html. Would that be possible with `PartialAsync` and is it good practice?

Answer (score 0):

In this article [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137972/net-core-mvc-tempdata-not-saving-data-locally-in-ajax-call)  it is stated that for the author the TempData doesn't work, for the user that answered - it worked.
And in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020843/session-not-retaining-tempdata-through-multiple-ajax-calls-to-controller) another user states that the IIS Express was the issue, so he switched to IIS (full).

After the research, the information is very scarce, but I've concluded 2 things:

The issue is either in the IIS or the TempData recognizes Http requests only if they invoke views. And AJAX calls do not switch to another view. This is just a guessing, because the information is scarce, as I said.